# How to set a release pipeline variable to null

Tags: azure-devops

I have a .json config file in my application. Using the variables tab when managing the release in Azure DevOps, I can substitute values in that .json file. However, I am unable to explicitly set a value to null instead of string "null" using this method. Is there a way to do this? I need the resulting json to look like

```
"setting": null
```

instead of

```
"setting": "null"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set the variable in Variables tab but don’t specify its value, its value is null.
[image]

However, when referring to this variable in scripts, it will be parsed to null string and is not null value.

For example, we have a test.json with below content.

```
    "setting": "debug",
    "environment": "dev"
}
```

If we use the command line task with below content.

```
echo Hello world

cat $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_tt/test.json

echo ""
echo "now replace: "

sed "s/\"debug\"/$testvar/g" $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_tt/test.json
```

The output result is below.
[image]

If you want to set it to null, just directly use null value with below content.

```
sed 's/\"debug\"/null/g' $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_tt/test.json
```

The output result is below.
[image]

And use`sed 's/\"debug\"/null/g' $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_tt/test.json >$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_tt/new_test.json` will write output to new_test.json file.

See: [How to Use sed to Find and Replace String in Files](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-sed-to-find-and-replace-string-in-files/) for details.

Comment: This is a pretty big hack IMO. I ended up doing a find/replace with PowerShell to get around it (your solution is essentially the same), but it is an extra step in the pipeline and is nowhere near as clean as if there was some way to explicitly specify null in the variables tab :(.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Currently there is no such way to implement this except directly replacing your config file. The product group might consider this feature if it is advised by many customers submitting [here](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/report?entry=suggestion&space=22). BTW, if my answer helps, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235), it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.